# Import python module in flutter using starflut

Tags: python, android, ios, flutter, dart

I am trying to develop a Flutter app for audio fingerprints processing. I am using [Starflut](https://github.com/srplab/starcore_for_flutter) for python integration. Here is simple example:

```
//python file for using from dart

def tt(a,b) :
    print (a, b)
    return 666,777
g1 = 123
def yy(a,b,z) :
    print(a,b,z)
    return {'jack': 4098, 'sape': 4139}

class Multiply :

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def multiply(self, a,b):
        print("multiply....",a,b)
        return a * b
```

---

```
//dart code which uses python

void _initStarCore() async {
    StarCoreFactory starcore = await Starflut.getFactory();
    StarServiceClass service = await starcore.initSimple("test", "123", 0, 0, []);
    srvGroup = await service["_ServiceGroup"];
    bool isAndroid = await Starflut.isAndroid();
    if (isAndroid == true) {
        String libraryDir = await Starflut.getNativeLibraryDir();
        String docPath = await Starflut.getDocumentPath();
        if (libraryDir.indexOf("arm64") > 0) {
            Starflut.unzipFromAssets("lib-dynload-arm64.zip", docPath, true);
        } else if (libraryDir.indexOf("x86_64") > 0) {
            Starflut.unzipFromAssets("lib-dynload-x86_64.zip", docPath, true);
        } else if (libraryDir.indexOf("arm") > 0) {
            Starflut.unzipFromAssets("lib-dynload-armeabi.zip", docPath, true);
        } else {
            Starflut.unzipFromAssets("lib-dynload-x86.zip", docPath, true);
        }
        await Starflut.copyFileFromAssets("python3.6.zip",
            "flutter_assets/starfiles", null);
    }
    await srvGroup.initRaw("python36", service);

    String resPath = await Starflut.getResourcePath();
    srvGroup.loadRawModule("python", "",
        resPath + "/flutter_assets/starfiles/" + "testpy.py", false);

    dynamic python = await service.importRawContext("python", "", false, "");

    StarObjectClass retobj = await python.call("tt", ["hello ", "world"]);
    print(await retobj[0]);
    print(await retobj[1]);

    print(await python["g1"]);

    StarObjectClass yy = await python.call("yy", ["hello ", "world", 123]);
    print(await yy.call("__len__",[]));

    StarObjectClass multiply = await service.importRawContext("python", "Multiply", true, "");
    StarObjectClass multiply_inst = await multiply.newObject(["", "", 33, 44]);
    print(await multiply_inst.getString());

    print(await multiply_inst.call("multiply", [11, 22]));

    await srvGroup.clearService();
    await starcore.moduleExit();
}
```

Now I need to import python library [Dejavu](https://github.com/worldveil/dejavu) for audio fingerprinting, but I do not know how to do that. There is nothing about it in starflut documentation or issues in their repository.

Has somebody faced same problem? Or maybe somebody has any suggestion how i can try to solve it?

Sorry for mistakes, hope the text is understandable:) English is not my native language.

Comment: I tried to add an existing module into python3.6.zip and then recompress to zip, but run into the error: `Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec`. (OSX)

Answer (score 6):

Did you read the repo [readme](https://github.com/worldveil/dejavu/blob/master/README.md) and [installation readme](https://github.com/worldveil/dejavu/blob/master/INSTALLATION.md) file?

If not, try this:

In your command prompt:

```
pip install PyDejavu
```

In the module where you need to import Dejavu:

```
from dejavu import Dejavu
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Where should I execute these commands? I get an error if I place `pip install PyDejavu` above `from dejavu import Dejavu ` in my .py file. Sorry if the question is dumb, I am new in python.

Comment: You have to type the first one in your command prompt (please search on google 'pip install command prompt') and the second in each module using dejavue.

Comment: If you are new in python you should practice a bit with basic concepts before starting using modules not included in default django package. Or it is going to be hard...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [chaquopy](https://pub.dev/packages/chaquopy) plugin for flutter, as it supports 90% of the python packages that you can use and integrate inside your flutter app.